# Is this a valid type of checking if argument is integer?

Tags: javascript

And are there any better options?

```
function isInteger(x) {
  // check if argument is a valid number and not NaN
  if ((typeof x !== 'number') || (x !== x)) throw Error('Not a valid number')
  // double binary inverse (inspired by `!!` operation)
  return x === ~~x;
}
```

Comment: `x !== x` will always be false regardless of what type or value `x` has.

Comment: speaking of `x !== x` — either i did not understood you correctly or you're wrong (`var x = 1; console.log(!!x)`

Comment: `x = 1; (x !== x)` returns `false`

Comment: @techfoobar Try `NaN`

Comment: the line i'm especially interested in is `return x === ~~x;`

Comment: @Oriol - Well, yes. `NaN` is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely.

JS numbers are 64-bit floats, but bitwise operators only support 32-bit integers. Then, they truncate numbers.

That's why you can use them to check if a number is an integer, e.g

```
x === ~~x;
x === (x|0);
x === (x&-1);
```

However, they won't work for integers greater than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or below -2<sup>32</sup>:

```
var x = Math.pow(2, 31);
x; // 2147483648
Number.isInteger(x); // true
x === ~~x; // false
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) instead. Have a look at the polyfill:

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && 
           isFinite(value) && 
           Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

Edit: Also there are [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) functions. Don't use `x !== x`.

Comment: Thank you, i'm aware of it. Interested in the solution itself.

Comment: The polyfill in the linked article works for older browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function works exactly as expected, it's checking if the variable sent throught the function call is really an integer, but you don't need to check if(x isn't equal to x), you can omit it(x !== x)

```
function isInteger(x) {
  if (typeof x !== 'number') throw Error('Not a valid number')
  return x === ~~x;
}
```

Comment: How about the situation, when we pass `NaN` as argument?